# Javascript print multiple page into one without opening it

Tags: javascript, printing

I have used javascript to print a page via iframe, it worked fine. Now I want to print multiple pages, each page in a frame within frameset at one time, one click, all the pages will be printed to one screen.

I don't know how to do it?

Print one page like reference here: https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/web-design-html-and-css/threads/275435/print-another-page-without-window-popup

Answer (score -1):

Your button / link has to call:

```
parent.print();
```

However frames and frameset are really old and must to be avoided, if needed just use iframe.

Comment: So what elements instead of frames and frameset because I want to print multiples page at one time. Could you please show me more detail to do it. Thanks so much!!

Comment: If you use iframes, just put your "print" button in "main" body (Es: <body><button id="myPrintAllButton"><iframe><div><iframe></body> and use a simplw window.print();